# A conjecture on uniform convergence of functions with a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness, uniform-convergence

So I was having a discussion with a friend about this problem and we have conflicting views. Here it is

We let $f_n: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions for $1 \leq n \leq N$ and we let $a_k^{(n)}$ be $N$ convergent sequences of numbers. Assume lim$_{k\rightarrow \infty}a_k^{(n)} = a_n$. Let $f = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n f_n$.

He thinks that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_k^{\{n\}} f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

But I do not think so. However, I can't think of any counterexample. I am fairly certain that this is not true. However, I do think that it converges uniformly to $f$ if $E$ is compact. This just makes sense to me, but I cannot figure out how to rigorously prove this.

So, (1) I think that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_k^{\{n\}} f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$. Edit: SOLVED

(2) $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_k^{\{n\}} f_n$ does  converge uniformly to $f$ if $E$ is compact.

(3)Edit: SOLVED $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_k^{\{n\}} f_n$ converges point-wise to $f$, my friend said this is true but can't prove. This is what I have so far. I can fix $x$ in $E$ and then look at |$\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_k^{\{n\}}f_n(x)$ - $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_nf_n(x)$|but from here I am stuck on how to show that it is indeed pointwise convergent.

Any help showing these would be great!

Comment: It is true for compact $E$ because that implies the $f_n$ are bounded. If $f_n$ is just a collection of bounded (not necessarily continuous) functions then the claim is true.

Comment: just make peace with your friend. math is not worth ruining a friendship.

Comment: lol we just had conflicting views, still good friends haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the continuous function $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R},$ $f(x)=1/x.$ Consider $a_k=\frac{k}{k+1}\to 1.$ Then,

$$\left|\frac{k}{k+1}f(x)-f(x)\right|=\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{x}.$$ That is, $\frac{k}{k+1}f$ doesn't converge uniformly to $f.$ Indeed, assume that given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$n\ge N \implies \left|\frac{n}{n+1}f(x)-f(x)\right|=\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{x}<\epsilon.$$ Now, this is equivalent to say $$x> \frac{1}{(n+1)\epsilon},$$ and thus the inequality is not satisfied for all $x\in (0,1/(n+1)\epsilon),$ what gives us a contradiction. Thus, we have shown that the convergence is no uniform.

If $E$ is bounded the answer is yes and can be obtained from the inequality

$$\left\|\sum_{n=1}^N a^n_kf_n-\sum_{n=1}^n a_nf_n\right\|_{\infty}\le \sum_{n=1}^N|a_k^n-a_n|\|f_n\|_{\infty}.$$

Since $f_n$ is continuous and $E$ is compact we have that $$\|f_n\|_\infty=\max_{x\in E} |f_n(x)|=M_ n<\infty.$$ Consider $M=\max\{M_ 1,\ldots,M_N\}.$ So, we have

$$\left\|\sum_{n=1}^N a^n_kf_n-\sum_{n=1}^n a_nf_n\right\|_{\infty}\le M\sum_{n=1}^N|a_k^n-a_n|.$$ That is, for any $x\in E$ it is

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N a^n_kf_n(x)-\sum_{n=1}^n a_nf_n(x)\right|
\le M\sum_{n=1}^N|a_k^n-a_n|.$$ Since

$$\sum_{n=1}^N|a_k^n-a_n|\to 0$$ we have shown that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: @Tim $$\|\sum_{n=1}^N a^n_kf_n-\sum_{n=1}^n a_nf_n\|_{\infty}= \|\sum_{n=1}^N ( a^n_k-a_n)f_n\|_{\infty}\le \sum_{n=1}^N \| ( a^n_k-a_n)f_n\|_{\infty}\le \sum_{n=1}^N|a_k^n-a_n|\|f_n\|_{\infty}.$$

Comment: Does it have something to do with pointwise convergence anywhere? I don't see how the inequality would tell us that there is uniform convergence. Could you possible explain it a little more. Thanks!

Comment: I have editted my answer to be a bit more explicit. If you have some doubt, please tell me.

Comment: ok that now makes perfect sense I was not considering an M at all when I was trying to work it out. This now makes great sense to me. Thank you! My only last question is now why the counter example for the uniform convergence is not so. Don't you need to show a  epsilon for k/(k+1)f to show it's not uniform convergent? Could I just have a slight little more explanation? Thanks!

Comment: I am having trouble seeing why there is no epsilon for the N that is a natural number

Comment: I have given some more details on this case.